# How to use regex within pandas_udf function in pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

My code is as follows:

```
@pandas_udf(BooleanType())
def is_one(iterator: Iterator[pd.Series]) -> Iterator[pd.Series]:
    for s in iterator:
        res = re.search("1", s)
        yield res != None

df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(["1", "2", "3"], columns=["v"]))
df.select(is_one(df.v)).show()
```

I am getting error:

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

It looks like my function is not iterating through strings. Why is that? And how could I use regex function within pandas_udf?

I tried Series to Series approach, but getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` on the series to apply your regex search:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType
import pandas as pd

@pandas_udf(BooleanType())
def is_one(ser: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return ser.apply(lambda s: re.search("1", s) is not None)
    # a neater way:
    # return ser.str.contains("1")

df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(["1", "2", "3"], columns=["v"]))

df.select(is_one(df.v)).show()
+---------+
|is_one(v)|
+---------+
|     true|
|    false|
|    false|
+---------+
```